# Replacing text in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code to replace current text inside an array of html divs with values coming from a JSON file:

```
    $.each($('.something'), function(){
        if($(this).text()=="1"){
            $(this).html(jsondata.CameraTypeLabel1);
        }else if($(this).text()=="2"){
            $(this).html(jsondata.CameraTypeLabel2);
        }
    });
```

I'd like to make it "dynamic": if I'd have 100 values, I don't want to copy/paste it 100 times.

Maybe it would be better creating an array "CameraTypeLabel" in the JSON string ?

EDIT: Fixed the selector, it was a typo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method can take a callback function - it'll be called for every element in the collection - and will use the returned value to set the element's html.

You can use bracket notation to access the key in your `jsondata`, so that you can dynamically get to the key you want with the string in the brackets:

```
$('.something').html(function () {
    return jsondata[ 'CameraTypeLabel' + $.text(this) ];
});
```

**Note:** `$.text(this)` is the same as `$(this).text()`, just a bit faster; it doesn't create a new jQuery object at every step in the loop.

---

If all you want to do is update the text, you can pass a function to [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) itself:

```
$('.something').text(function (i, oldText) {
    return jsondata[ 'CameraTypeLabel' + oldText ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the elements you want to replace are in the same order as the json content is. Ex.:

```
<div class="something">0</div>
    <div class="irrelevant shitty div that won't be selected"></div>
<div class="something">1</div>
<div class="something">2</div>
```

If so, no `.text()` check is needed and you can just use the index.

```
   $('.something').each(function(i) {

        var arrayOfDivs = ["something0", "something1", "something2"], //array of html divs
            jsondata = "whatevaaa is coming in from json"; //value coming from json

            var index = arrayOfDivs.indexOf("something" + [i]); //find element to be replaced

            if (index !== -1) { //check to see if element was found
                arrayOfDivs[index] = jsondata; // replace the current text of matched element, in arrayOfDivs, with what comes in from json
                //You can also replace the html in the div from here:
                //$(this).html(arrayOfDivs[index]);
            }
    });
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/vyXPV/**